# Implementing linguistic rules to transliterate Thai words

Tags: java, algorithm, nlp

I can't find any open code in order to transliterate Thai script to a phonetic equivalent.
For example:
`สวัสดี` which can be transliterated to `sà-wàt-di`
It's like pinyin for Chinese. This enables learners of a foreign script to get the proper pronunciation even if one can't read the script.

There is a defined standard by ISO, which isn't usable since it's an exact transliteration, char by char. But Thai uses chars in front above and after other chars.

There are websites and software that can do transliteration automatically, so it's possible to do this automatically. Nonetheless there's no open code available and I searched in English as well as Thai language. There are some research papers on that but always without logic or code, describing that topic in a high-level fashion.

My approach so far:
I define the phonemes that are possible in the Thai language and transcribe them to English:

We have some simple letters that always make the same sound:

```
/*
x - consonants:
ก   ->  g
ข   ->  kh
ค   ->  kh
ฆ   ->  kh
ง   ->  ng
จ   ->  dsch
ฉ   ->  dsch
ช   ->  dsch
ซ   ->  s
ฌ   ->  dsch
ญ   ->  i
ฎ   ->  d
ฏ   ->  dt
ฐ   ->  th
ฑ   ->  th
ฒ   ->  th
ณ   ->  n
ด   ->  d
ต   ->  dt
ถ   ->  th
ท   ->  th
ธ   ->  th
น   ->  n
บ   ->  b
ป   ->  bp
ผ   ->  ph
ฝ   ->  f
พ   ->  ph
ฟ   ->  f
ภ   ->  ph
ม   ->  m
ย   ->  i
ร   ->  r
ล   ->  l
ว   ->  w
ศ   ->  s
ษ   ->  s
ส   ->  s
ห   ->  h
ฬ   ->  l
อ   ->  (silent)
ฮ   ->  h
```

Then we have vowels that contain the above consonants and finally make a syllable. In the vowel compounds below, the possible position of a consonant is substituted by an x.
The Z is a substitution of the consonants that can come at the end of a syllable. Not all of the above consonants can appear at position Z, only the ones described further below under Z.

```
Vowels With เ
เxียว   ->  iauw
เxือย   ->  üüai
เx็อ    ->  ööh
เxิZ    ->  öh
เxาะ    ->  o
เxะ ->  e
เxียะ   ->  ia
เxือะ   ->  üa
เx็ว    ->  eu
เx็Z    ->  e
เxา ->  au
เxียZ   ->  iia
เxือZ   ->  üüa
เxอะ    ->  ö
เxZ ->  eh
เxว ->  eeu
เxีย    ->  iia
เxือ    ->  üüa
เxอ ->  öö
เx  ->  ee
เxย ->  ööi

Vowels With แ
แx็ว    ->  äu
แxว ->  ääu
แxะ ->  ä
แx็Z    ->  ä
แxZ ->  ää
แx  ->  ää

Vowels With ไ , ใ Or โ
โxZ ->  oo
โx  ->  oo
โxว ->  oou
โxะ ->  o
ไx  ->  ai
ใx  ->  ai
ไxย ->  ai
โxย ->  ooi

Vowels With อิ Or อี
xิZ ->  i
xิ  ->  i
xิว ->  iu
xีZ ->  ii
xี      ->  ii

Vowels With อุ Or อู
xุZ ->  u
xุ  ->  u
xุย ->  ui
xูZ ->  uu
xู  ->  uu

Vowels With อึ Or อื
xึZ ->  ü
xึ  ->  ü
xือ ->  üü
xืZ ->  üü

Vowels With า
xาย ->  aai
xาว ->  aau
xาZ ->  aa
xา  ->  aa

Vowels With อ
x็อZ    ->  o
x็อย    ->  oi
xอย ->  ooi
xอZ ->  oo
xอ  ->  oo

Vowels With อั Or ว
xัวะ    ->  ua
xัย ->  ai
xัว ->  ua
xัZ ->  a
xวย ->  uai
xวZ ->  ua

Remaining Vowels
xะ  ->  a
x่า ->  am
Inherent 'o'    ->  o

Z - possible final consonants:
ก   ->  g
ง   ->  ng
ด   ->  dt
น   ->  n
บ   ->  b
ม   ->  m
*/
```

I am not sure what approach would be short enough to contain all of those rules, without retyping a lot of if/else or switch/cases. Furthermore a syllable string can contain an optional character: a tone mark. This is not always the case but often. So my approach would be, to first strip the vowel string from the tone mark and then process some rule like:

```
// example เดียว ->     diau
string vowel001 = "iau";

string thaiword = "เดียว";
if( thaiword.substring(0,1)=="เ" &&
    thaiword.substring(1,2)=="ี" && /*the unicode character moves above " which we don't have to care about*/
    thaiword.substring(2,3)=="ย" && 
    thaiword.substring(3,4)=="ว"){
    return getConsonantTransliteration(string.pos.1) + vowel001;
}
```

Is there a faster and more oop approach to do that, instead of writing such a rule for every possibility?

Edit2:

Currently the fastest way seems to be a Regular Expression approach:

Given the example `เอียว` vowel and all it's possible variations:

```
เลียว
เลี้ยว
เหลียว
เหลี้ยว
เหี้ยว

find:       เ(ห{0,1})([ก-ฮ])ี([่้๊๋]{0,1})ยว
replace:    silenth[\1] initialcons[\2] tone[\3]

เลียว -->   silenth[] initialcons[ล] tone[]
เลี้ยว -->  silenth[] initialcons[ล] tone[้]
เหลียว -->  silenth[ห] initialcons[ล] tone[]
เหลี้ยว --> silenth[ห] initialcons[ล] tone[้]
เหี้ยว -->  silenth[] initialcons[ห] tone[้]
```

Comment: Hi there? did you find some way to convert thai language to phoneme?